# Margin of child element won't force window to show scrollbars when html element has height: 100%

Tags: html, css, safari

If I have the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .square {
      background-color: red;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 2000px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="square"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would expect that the margin of the div would cause the window to become scrollable. This works as expected in Chrome, but in Safari the window is not scrollable. Why is this? Is this a bug?

The html height 100% is deliberate.

Comment: Maybe if you play with the `overflow` css property? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: `html {height:100%}` is probably causing the issue. Is there any reason to use it?

Comment: @Lucas yes that is causing the issue but it is necessary for my layout.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Safari ignores the margin-bottom if nothing follows below that element.

I tried to put an additional element *below* the `.square` div that is made invisible by `height: 0px;` (and also by `color: #fff;` in this particular case). You don't see that element, but now the scrollbar appears, the padding is not ignored anymore:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJRexY

I then tried just to use only a space inside that "invisible" element, but that didn't work the same way - there *has* to be some "real content". However, with a `&nbsp;` as only content of that element it works too.

In fact, you don't even need another DIV, just adding a `&nbsp;` after the `.square` div also makes the scrollbar appear in Safari.